# Smaller emit view for couchdb

Tags: couchdb

What is the advantage of say

```
emit([doc.key1,doc.key2], 1);
```

vs

```
emit([doc.key1,doc.key2], doc);
```

and call the doc via ?include_docs=true

Would this actually save on couchdb space ( view sizes are shorter ) ? Also, would CPU suffer since doc is not integrated
in the emit ?

What's the Pros and Cons and when to use one over the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `emit(..., 1);` is needed for reduce functions like `_sum`, `_count` or `_stats`, because they need a number to work with.

Using `emit(..., doc);` will truly *duplicate* the document, so it will be stored in the view file on disk.

Using `emit(..., null);` will not duplicate the document, but because couchdb knows which `doc` is the source for the `emit()` it can be "re-attached" with `?include_docs=true`. The key-based lookup is a little bit slower, but will not do any harm.

More on this topic can be found in [the wonderful documentation](http://docs.ehealthafrica.org/couchdb-best-practices/#do-not-emit-entire-docs).

*My recommendation:*

- Use `emit(..., 1)` when reduce is needed, and `emit(..., null)` when not.
- There are very few cases where `emit(..., doc);` has benefits.

A cool trick is linking a different document in the view instead of the current `doc` with `emit(..., { _id : doc.commentId })`.

Comment: This is an awesome response. Thanks! Can you give me a good tutorial link on how to link different document on the emit ?

Comment: Best documentation i know is this website. For best result read the whole, or at least the chapter about "views" :)   http://docs.ehealthafrica.org/couchdb-best-practices/#views

Comment: I don't think you need `emit(..., 1)` to use `_count`. Any value should do, including `emit(..., null)`. In practice, `emit(..., 1)` should rarely be useful.